# Что лучше учить: Extjs или jqueryUI?

Tags: jquery, extjs

Всем привет. Интересуют эти 2 технологии. Какую из них выбрать для изучения, чтобы создавать интерфейсы? Интересует: есть ли будущее в этих технологиях? В какой больше возможностей?

Каковы сильные стороны ExtJS, что JQuery не хватает? Какие преимущества ExtJS перед JQuery?
Как сейчас востребованы эти технологии?

Всем спасибо!

Comment: >Не стоит задавать вопросы-опросы, где каждый ответ является верным, форум - не подходящее место для статистических исследований и реальной ценности подобные темы не имеют.

- [Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8)

Comment: @Spectre, ТС интересуется как раз конкретными различиями между библиотеками, а не спрашивает, кому что больше нравится.

Comment: это вопрос из разряда: "Я ничего не хочу сам решать, скажите мне что делать", ТС приложил минимум усилий, чтобы узнать различия между этими библиотеками, если бы он изначально поискал что-то по сабжу, а уж только потом спрашивал: "Вот я использую ... и мне кажется, что для такой-то задачи оно не очень подходит, т.к. ... и ..., может я делаю это не правильно и лучше было бы использовать ...?" я бы даже плюс поставил.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Они решают разные проблемы. Jquery UI нужен для пользователей, чтобы все красиво и удобно было. 
ExtJS тяжелый фреймфорк, на нем делают чаще интерфейс для работы менеджеров и т.п.

Они из разных плоскостей, учите все. Jquery не такой тяжелый, выучите быстро. А потом учите Extjs, вот он сложный.

Вообще определитесь - для каких целей вам это нужно? Можно и танком забивать гвоздь :)

Comment: Прочитайте описание их, и поймете разницу. Они оба умеют делать то, что не может другой.

Answer (score 4):

ExtJS не бессплатный для комерческого использования поэтому смотреть лушче в сторону jQuery UI.

ExtJS значительно лучше подходит для представления табличных данных. Вообще ExtJS довольно тяжелый и его очень редко используют на фронтэнде - обычно его используют для бекенда тоесть админки.

Есть еще MochaUI фреймворк который полностью бесплатный http://pat.cullen.co.za/project/WindowPicker/Demo/

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/), [демки](http://qooxdoo.org/demos)